# Looking for an algorithm for multi-path funnel analysis

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, graph, statistics

Suppose we have a dataset with each instance: {uid, action, TS}. The funnel algorithm (e.x https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/parametric-functions/#windowfunnel) looks at a set of sequential actions [action1, action2, action3] and generates the retention after each action.

The funnel algorithm assumes there is one path from the first action (starting node) to the last (target) action (last node). I am looking for an algorithm to do funnel analysis for multiple paths, as shown in the figure below. I have a feeling that there is an algorithm specifically designed for this problem since it is a very common scenario in the industry. Can we solve this w/ graph theory?
[image]

Comment: Interesting question, however, pretty sure it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem. Maybe try math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com instead. On the face of it, it seems like constructing transition matrices (as for a Markov chain) for each step and then multiplying them together would yield the desired result. At each step, the matrix multiplication is effectively adding up terms which look like (where we are) times (where we might go) to get to the next step. Kind of waving my hands here, hope that helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thank you for replying. My intuition tells me this can be modeled as a Markov chain as well. Taking each action and populate a state transition matrix should work.